# CMake link code with OpenCV to work on both ubuntu AND fedora

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, dynamic-linking

I have a library that I can compile and use on both Ubuntu and Fedora (the version is not very important). This library links to OpenCV dynamically.

However, the issue comes when I want to build the library on one of the two distributions and use it on the other. Let's say that I compiled the library on Ubuntu and then I use it under Fedora.

I cannot use the library because it cannot find the corresponding OpenCV libraries that were used when compiling and linking under ubuntu (this is the output of ldd under Fedora):

```
    libopencv_stitching.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_alphamat.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_bgsegm.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_bioinspired.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_ccalib.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_freetype.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_fuzzy.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_hfs.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_img_hash.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_intensity_transform.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_line_descriptor.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_mcc.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_optflow.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_phase_unwrapping.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_quality.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_rapid.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_reg.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_rgbd.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_saliency.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_shape.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_stereo.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_tracking.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_ximgproc.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_viz.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_highgui.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_datasets.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_text.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_ml.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_videoio.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_video.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_calib3d.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_features2d.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_flann.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_dnn.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_plot.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_imgproc.so.4.5d => not found
    libopencv_core.so.4.5d => not found
```

If I compile the library under Fedora, the same output shows that it is valid:

```
    libopencv_stitching.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_stitching.so.406 (0x00007fc830480000)
    libopencv_alphamat.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_alphamat.so.406 (0x00007fc831209000)
    libopencv_bgsegm.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_bgsegm.so.406 (0x00007fc8311ed000)
    libopencv_bioinspired.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_bioinspired.so.406 (0x00007fc830447000)
    libopencv_ccalib.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_ccalib.so.406 (0x00007fc8303f1000)
    libopencv_cvv.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_cvv.so.406 (0x00007fc8302ba000)
    libopencv_freetype.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_freetype.so.406 (0x00007fc8302af000)
    libopencv_fuzzy.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_fuzzy.so.406 (0x00007fc83029d000)
    libopencv_hfs.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_hfs.so.406 (0x00007fc83028a000)
    libopencv_img_hash.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_img_hash.so.406 (0x00007fc830275000)
    libopencv_intensity_transform.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_intensity_transform.so.406 (0x00007fc830251000)
    libopencv_line_descriptor.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_line_descriptor.so.406 (0x00007fc830225000)
    libopencv_mcc.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_mcc.so.406 (0x00007fc8301c0000)
    libopencv_rapid.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_rapid.so.406 (0x00007fc8301ad000)
    libopencv_reg.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_reg.so.406 (0x00007fc830193000)
    libopencv_rgbd.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_rgbd.so.406 (0x00007fc8300c3000)
    libopencv_saliency.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_saliency.so.406 (0x00007fc83009f000)
    libopencv_shape.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_shape.so.406 (0x00007fc830078000)
    libopencv_stereo.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_stereo.so.406 (0x00007fc830054000)
    libopencv_tracking.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_tracking.so.406 (0x00007fc82fe61000)
    libopencv_datasets.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_datasets.so.406 (0x00007fc82fdde000)
    libopencv_text.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_text.so.406 (0x00007fc82fd78000)
    libopencv_plot.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_plot.so.406 (0x00007fc82fd6e000)
    libopencv_gapi.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_gapi.so.406 (0x00007fc82f800000)
    libopencv_aruco.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_aruco.so.406 (0x00007fc82fd0d000)
    libopencv_barcode.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_barcode.so.406 (0x00007fc82fcf2000)
    libopencv_dnn_objdetect.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_dnn_objdetect.so.406 (0x00007fc82fce6000)
    libopencv_dnn_superres.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_dnn_superres.so.406 (0x00007fc82fcd6000)
    libopencv_quality.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_quality.so.406 (0x00007fc82fcc3000)
    libopencv_ml.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_ml.so.406 (0x00007fc82fc3b000)
    libopencv_dpm.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_dpm.so.406 (0x00007fc82fc22000)
    libopencv_highgui.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_highgui.so.406 (0x00007fc82f795000)
    libopencv_face.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_face.so.406 (0x00007fc82f717000)
    libopencv_hdf.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_hdf.so.406 (0x00007fc82fc12000)
    libopencv_structured_light.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_structured_light.so.406 (0x00007fc82fbfe000)
    libopencv_phase_unwrapping.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_phase_unwrapping.so.406 (0x00007fc82fbf2000)
    libopencv_viz.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_viz.so.406 (0x00007fc82f6b5000)
    libopencv_superres.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_superres.so.406 (0x00007fc82f691000)
    libopencv_optflow.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_optflow.so.406 (0x00007fc82f630000)
    libopencv_ximgproc.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_ximgproc.so.406 (0x00007fc82f200000)
    libopencv_surface_matching.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_surface_matching.so.406 (0x00007fc82f5e3000)
    libopencv_videostab.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_videostab.so.406 (0x00007fc82f5a0000)
    libopencv_videoio.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_videoio.so.406 (0x00007fc82f508000)
    libopencv_video.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_video.so.406 (0x00007fc82f485000)
    libopencv_wechat_qrcode.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_wechat_qrcode.so.406 (0x00007fc82f19b000)
    libopencv_xobjdetect.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_xobjdetect.so.406 (0x00007fc82f46e000)
    libopencv_imgcodecs.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.406 (0x00007fc82f137000)
    libopencv_objdetect.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_objdetect.so.406 (0x00007fc82f0a6000)
    libopencv_calib3d.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_calib3d.so.406 (0x00007fc82ee00000)
    libopencv_features2d.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_features2d.so.406 (0x00007fc82ed36000)
    libopencv_flann.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_flann.so.406 (0x00007fc82f035000)
    libopencv_dnn.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_dnn.so.406 (0x00007fc82e800000)
    libopencv_xphoto.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_xphoto.so.406 (0x00007fc82ecf5000)
    libopencv_photo.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_photo.so.406 (0x00007fc82e763000)
    libopencv_imgproc.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_imgproc.so.406 (0x00007fc82e000000)
    libopencv_core.so.406 => /lib64/libopencv_core.so.406 (0x00007fc82dc00000)
```

Obviously, the libraries have different names but the functions should work... I have compiled everything with the fPIC flag. I do not see what I have to add in my CMakeLists.txt file such that the library loads the local opencv and not the one linked during build.

Thanks

Comment: "Obviously, the libraries have different names but the functions should work..." - No, you are wrong. Different *so-versions* (the extension after `.so`) usually mean, that given libraries are **binary incompatible**. That is, a library/executable linked with one of those version may to not work with other version. You need to build your library twice, once for Fedora and once for Ubuntu. You could read about so-versions e.g. [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475/how-do-so-shared-object-numbers-work).

Comment: you should statically link to opencv if you want to use executables across distributions

Comment: Then I do have a second issue. If the system updates the version of OpenCV (even a minor version), the software will not work. This makes no sense for backward compatibility...